# Where should I define my MUI X license key on a storybook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, storybook, mui-x

Where should I define my license key on a storybook?

> Where to install the key?
> You must call setLicenseKey before React renders the first component. You only need to install the key once in your application. - [MUI Docs](https://mui.com/x/introduction/licensing/)

But this case is more complicated on storybook and I get the message *License key expired* when I define my license in the story or in my component index file.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this at `.storybook/preview.js` in the decorator:

```
import { customTheme } from "../src/styles";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material";
import { LicenseInfo } from "@mui/x-license-pro"    

export const decorators = [
(Story) => {
LicenseInfo.setLicenseKey(process.env.REACT_APP__MUI_KEY);

return (
  <ThemeProvider theme={customTheme}>
    <Story />
  </ThemeProvider>
);
}];
```

- I have the licence key in a `.env` file, so both the react app and storybook read it from there. The variable must be prefixed with `REACT_APP__`
- In this example we are using also a custom theme, so we wrap the story in it (you would do the same with react router, for instance).

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you're able to resolve this by adding the license key to `.storybook/preview.js`: https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/overview#configure-story-rendering